# How to prevent reinitialization of component when other JS is interacting with alpine.js components?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm using Alpine.js 3.2.1 alongside with Glider.js carousel.
I'm having a problem with double initialization of a component. When Glider carousel is being initialized it fires x-init function second time. The result is that for example event is fired twice or x-for template rendered twice.
Do you have any similar issues? How do I prevent such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue when using Glider.js with Alpine.js

The solution was to set `skipTrack: true` when initialising the glider and adding in the track `<div>` manually.

This removed the need for Glider to remove the already initialised DOM elements then add them back in with a new parent element which is what was causing the re-init.

```
<div class="glider draggable">
    <div class="glider-track">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
</div>

new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider'), {
  skipTrack: true
});
```